# Find all the json files which are invalid in directory tree structure

Tags: python, json, linux, xargs

I am trying to figure out invalid JSON file in my directory tree. I have more than 100+ JSON files so trying to see if there is any easy way by which I can run some linux command to figure out which JSON files are invalid. I want to know all those file names.

I tried this command but this doesn't give me anything on my console and I do have bunch of invalid JSON files.

```
find . -name \*.json -exec echo {} \; -exec python -m json.tool "{}" \; 2>&1 | grep "No JSON" -B 1
```

I am trying to run it on my mac.

Comment: Mac or linux? They're two different environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python you could do

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path
import json

# scan subdirs from current directory
for jsonfile in Path(".").glob("**/*.json"):
    try:
        json.load(open(jsonfile))
        print(jsonfile, "success")
    except Exception as e:
        print(jsonfile, "fail", e)
```

Comment: How would I invoke this script in terminal? I receive the following error, "ImportError: No module name pathlib"

Comment: Which version of python? pathlib was introduced in python 3.4, back in 2014.

Comment: I had to update python and that resolved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` or `zsh`, using `jq` to validate JSON files:

```sh
find . -name "*.json" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r filename; do
    if ! jq . "$filename" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "$filename is invalid"
    fi
done
```